# MS-CHAPv2 Success packet is badly formed

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, pptp

When I tried to connect to work PPTP VPN by using Network Manager, it's fail. From syslog, I see that there is **MS-CHAPv2 Success packet is badly formed** before my connection terminated. The syslog as below:

```
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0179] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b" name="VPN 1" pid=24257 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0334] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 27365
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0439] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0538] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0565] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pppd[27369]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[27369]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pppd[27369]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pppd[27369]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pppd[27369]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[27369]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[27369]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139873.0630] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/42)
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pptp[27374]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza systemd-udevd[27373]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Oct  8 14:51:13 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:938]: Outgoing call established (call ID 7775, peer's call ID 38599).
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza gnome-shell[1695]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._dialog is null#012_onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza gnome-shell[1695]: message repeated 1002 times: [ JS ERROR: TypeError: this._dialog is null#012_onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9]
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza gnome-shell[1695]: JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties#012_onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza gnome-shell[1695]: JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties#012_onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1004]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 36270
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1006]:   send_accm is 00000000, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1011]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pppd[27369]: MS-CHAPv2 Success packet is badly formed.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[27369]: MS-CHAPv2 Success packet is badly formed.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[27369]: CHAP authentication failed
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pppd[27369]: CHAP authentication failed
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pppd[27369]: Connection terminated.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[27369]: Connection terminated.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <warn>  [1602139874.8414] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139874.8415] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139874.8415] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[7685]: <info>  [1602139874.8445] vpn-connection[0x5579d0f90540,34f9d336-6d43-4ee4-8151-c1d9142f287b,"VPN 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza gnome-shell[1695]: Removing a network device that was not added
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27374]: nm-pptp-service-27365 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:226]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pppd[27369]: Terminating on signal 15
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza NetworkManager[27369]: Terminating on signal 15
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27374]: nm-pptp-service-27365 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:238]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pppd[27369]: Exit.
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Oct  8 14:51:14 reza pptp[27385]: nm-pptp-service-27365 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
```

This is my [VPN settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB8Y6.png). I've tried other settings like only tick MSCHAPv2, changing Security setting to All Available (Default) and untick MPPE but it still does not work. Other than this, I've tried to connect to the VPN using Windows OS and surprisingly it works. Then, I tried to use the same VPN settings on Windows machine to my Ubuntu machine, but it still does not work.

I wonder if **MS-CHAPv2 Success packet is badly formed** issue has anything to do with my settings or is it a bug? Because I found a link about it but that link was for l2tp not pptp that I am using.

https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/issues/144

Answer (score 0):

See the following Ubuntu SRU request to backport the patch to handle non-compliant PPP success packets :

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ppp/+bug/1890814

Vote by clicking the "Does this bug affect you? link on that page. The more people that vote, the sooner the patch will be back ported.

It affects all PPP based VPN clients on Linux.

The actual bug is on the VPN server running on Windows Server, but strangely it doesn't affect all Windows Servers, only a minority for some reason.